# bash set variable to command output

Tags: bash, shell-script

Trying bash shell scripting and running into small issue:

```
# hostname --short
7phdsn01
# virsh --readonly list --state-running --name
Nagios

# set $(hostname --short)=$(virsh --readonly list --state-running --name)
# echo $?
0
# echo $7phdsn01
phdsn01
#
```

Please advise.

---

```
# unset $7phdsn01
# set $(hostname --short)=$(virsh --readonly list --state-running --name)
# echo $7phdsn01
phdsn01
#
```

Comment: @MichaelHomer please see my updated question with output for your comment.

Comment: Your `set $(hostname ...)=$(virsh ...)` will just set `$1` (the 1st positional parameter) to the `7phdsn01=Nagios` string and will succeed, that's why you get `$? = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

The `set` command does not set values of shell variables like that in `bash`. You may want to try with `declare` instead.

It looks as if you want to use a variable named after the hostname.  Unfortunately, the hostname starts with a digit, so it can't be used as the name of a variable.

The command `echo $7phdsn01` outputs `phdsn01` since `$7` (the 7th positional parameter) is unset and expands to nothing, followed by the rest of the string.

I would probably have used

```
declare -A state

state["$(hostname --short)"]=$(virsh --readonly list --state-running --name)
```

This would create an associative array called `state`.  The next line sets the value for the key given by the `hostname --state` command to the output of the `virsh` command.

The values and keys of the `state` array could then be had like this:

```
for host in "${!state[@]}"; do
    printf 'Host %s is in state %s\n' "$host" "${state[$host]}"
done
```

If you're doing this for a single host, then obviously there is no need to be that fancy. Instead just use two variables:

```
host=$(hostname --short)
state=$(virsh --readonly list --state-running --name)

printf 'Host %s is in state %s\n' "$host" "$state"
```